# Selecting dimension table from SSAS

Tags: ssas, mdx

I'm trying to figure out how to get the data in a dimension via SSAS/MDX. Example:

```
DIMFileStatus
--------------
FileStatusID, FileStatusName
1             New
2             Updated
3             Deleted
```

If I run a simple query like:

```
SELECT [DimFileStatuses].[FileStatusName].members ON 0
FROM [status]
```

I get the following:

```
All  New  Updated  Deleted
--------------------------
1      1       1        1
```

What I want is:

```
FileStatusID  FileStatusName
          1    New
          2    Updated
          3    Deleted
```

How can I structure my query to get the results in the format I want?
Thanks!

---

MORE INFO:

If I try to create a custom measure:

```
WITH MEMBER Measures.[custom] AS [DimFileStatuses].[FileStatusID].CURRENTMEMBER.MEMBERVALUE
SELECT [DimFileStatuses].[FileStatusName].members on 1,
[Measures].[custom] ON 0  
FROM [status]
```

I get:

```
        custom
--------------
all     (null)
New     (null)
Updated (null)
Deleted (null)
```

Comment: Always include a tag for the primary language the question pertains to (SQL in this case), otherwise your question won't have visibility to subject matter experts. Also, the language tag usually gives your code block snazzy syntax highlighting.

Comment: @AdiInbar Actually, here the language is MDX, not SQL

Comment: @FrankPl Sorry, my mistake. I fixed the tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
SELECT {}
       ON COLUMNS,
       [DimFileStatuses].[FileStatusID].[FileStatusID].Members
        *
       [DimFileStatuses].[FileStatusName].[FileStatusName].Members
       ON ROWS
  FROM [status]
```

Using the level that is named like the attribute name excludes the all member, and the Autoexists feature of Analysis Services should take care that all combinations of `FileStatusID` and `FileStatusName` returned by the cross join actually exist in the dimension table. This avoids pairs like `(1, Updated)`.